# Razor Page Async return of list

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asynchronous, razor-pages

I'm working in VS 2022 .net7 with sql server 2019 and Razor pages. I'm using the ASP.Net Core Web App template. I used scaffolding to generate starter pages for database access - and that worked very well.

This scaffold code provided the basic data for my index page.

This is the scaffold code:

```
 public IList<myPosts> myPosts { get;set; } = default!;

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_context.myPosts != null)
            {
                myPosts = await _context.myPosts.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
```

However, I need to filter the data. And this is most of the code I need to filter the data:

```
namespace someBlog.Pages
{
    public class FAQlistModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly someBlog.Data.someBlogContext _context;

        public FAQlistModel(someBlog.Data.someBlogContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<myPosts> myPosts { get;set; } = default!;

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_context.myPosts != null)
            {
                var myposts = (from x in _context.myPosts
                               where x.IsApproved == "FAQ"
                               orderby x.PublishDate
                               select new myPosts
                               {
                                   Id = x.Id,
                                   Title = x.Title,
                                   Summary = x.Summary,
                                   Content = x.Content.Substring(0, 200),
                                   /*more fields*/
                               }).ToList();

                myPosts = myposts;
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

This does provide the selected records with the data formated correctly.  However, I get this warning "Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await....."

Although I don't know much about async coding protocols, I'd like to stay with the async code as generated by scaffolding - And, I don't need much database interaction beyond what scaffolding provides.

I'm looking for a way to fix my code so it runs asynchronous.  Although this code doesn't work, this is essentially what I'd like to do:

```
myPosts = await myposts;
```

Everything I've tried so far just produces errors.  Thanks

Comment: It seems you want to change `myposts` to async query, Have you tried to `.ToListAsync()`?

Comment: I've tried that at both the end of the select and on the last line - both times produces errors,

Comment: I mean change your query to `var myposts = await _context.myPosts.Where(x => x.IsApproved == "FAQ").OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate).Select(x => new myPosts { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Summary =x.Summary, Content = x.Content.Substring(0, 200) }).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Wonderful!  That worked!  How do I mark this as the answer?  I see - I marked it and thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use async code in your code, you can try to change your code like:

```
    public IList<myPosts> myPosts { get;set; } = default!;

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (_context.myPosts != null)
        {
            var myposts = await _context.myPosts.Where(x => x.IsApproved == "FAQ").OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate).Select(x => new myPosts { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Summary =x.Summary, Content = x.Content.Substring(0, 200) }).ToListAsync();

            myPosts = myposts;
       }
   }
```